# Need to install rpm package inside docker container without internet connectivity

Tags: linux, docker, rpm

I have a machine which has no internet connectivity and no access to any docker repository (so no image pulls are possible). I want to install memcached and I have the .rpm file available.

When I want to install on the host machine I execute the command `rpm -ivh memcached-1.4.15-10.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm` . But I suppose that is because the rpm package manager comes pre-installed on the host OS.

In the docker container I load the .rpm file and in the dockerfile I include the command `RUN rpm -ivh memcached-1.4.15-10.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm`. After that I get the following error:

`/bin/sh: 1: rpm: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c rpm -ivh /home/memcached-1.4.15-10.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm' returned a non-zero code: 127`

I suppose that is because in a docker container the OS has the bare minimum installation. So how do I install the rpm package manager inside the container without internet connection? Is there an installable file for it.

I understand it is not the best practice to **not** use a central repository for images. Want to know if installing without internet is even possible?

I am creating the container on a CentOS machine right now. And following is the dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime

WORKDIR /home
#mempkgtest folder contains the .rpm file
COPY ${source:-mempkgtest} .

RUN rpm -ivh /home/memcached-1.4.15-10.el7_3.1.x86_64.rpm

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "--info"]
```

Comment: what about to make own image with dotnet and memcached? just go to Your container with internet access install memcache and then create an image from container that has all You need.

Comment: actually, there is no internet access at any point of time. but i can have installable files that i can load into container. so i am thinking that i can install the rpm installer inside the container and then install the memcached service using its .rpm file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker image microsoft/dotnet is build on top of buildpack-deps:jessie-scm (from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/~/dockerfile/)) which is build on top debian:jessie (from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/buildpack-deps/) and [here](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/b0fc01aa5e3aed6820d8fed6f3301e0542fbeb36/jessie/curl/Dockerfile)).

debian does not use [rpm](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) package manager, it uses [deb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) format for packages. /bin/sh kindly informs you, that is hasn't found rpm manager by saying `/bin/sh: 1: rpm: not found`. You can read how to install rpm packages on debian [here](https://wiki.debian.org/RPM#Install_a_.RPM_in_Debian).

Anyway, why don't you use deb file and dpkg package manager? You can find memcached pacakge for debian jessie [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/memcached). You can do smth like this in your dockerfile:

```
ADD http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/memcached/memcached_1.4.21-1.1+deb8u1_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i memcached_1.4.21-1.1+deb8u1_amd64.deb
```

And remember, you will need to copy dependencies too.

Why don't you make your **docker image** on machine **with internet access**, than export docker image using `docker export` and then **copy and import** it on your **destination** machine? Such way is **simpler** and `apt-get` will resolve and install all `memcached` dependencies for you.

Comment: okk. the docker export option seems the best choice. wasn't aware of it. Thanks!

Comment: just browsed a little bit. `docker export` seems to be for a container. but there is a `docker image save` and then a `docker image load` which should work. will go with that

Comment: but You're installing dependencies inside of running container by logging into via shell (`exec -it bash`) that's why `docker export`